# how to get value from odoo purchase lines order to stock.picking lines?

Tags: python, odoo

i'am added analytic account field on stock move model, I need as the stock move lines get quantity form PO lines to get analytic account field form lines when I confirm the order, 
how can I do that

```
 class StockMove(models.Model):
_inherit = "stock.move"

 analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one(string='Analytic Account',comodel_name='account.analytic.account',)
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [_prepare_stock_moves](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/purchase_stock/models/purchase.py#L306) method which prepares the stock moves data for one order line and returns a list of dictionary ready to be used in `stock.move's create()`.

```
class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

    @api.multi
    def _prepare_stock_moves(self, picking):
        res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self)._prepare_stock_moves(picking)
        res[0]['analytic_account_id'] = self.account_analytic_id.id
        return res
```

To get field values from purchase order use the inverse_name `order_id`.

```
res[0]['analytic_account_id'] = self.order_id.account_analytic_id.id
```

**Edit:**

To use the same logic on production orders, you can set the account when you mark the order as done:

```
class ManufacturingOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one(string='Analytic Account', comodel_name='account.analytic.account')

    @api.multi
    def button_mark_done(self):           
        for order in self:
            for move in order.move_finished_ids:
                move.analytic_account_id = order.analytic_account_id
        res = super(ManufacturingOrder, self).button_mark_done()
        return res
```

Comment: it's working Great Bro, really thank you 
but if i added I analytic account field in PO form not product line how can I add this field to all picking lines

Comment: What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: i'am aslo added many2one analytic account field in production order I need to add it picking moves that created form that order

Comment: Do you need to use the same `analytic account` on all moves?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215108/discussion-between-mohamed-fouad-and-kenly).